# How to write a scope for closed or expired objects - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> I am totally confused on how to write a scope that displays events
>   that have either been closed or expired. if one could advise me, i
>   would be very grateful

schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161116132520) do
  create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.date     "date"
    t.string   "city"
    t.boolean  "close"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end
end
```

i tried the below scopes but no luck:

```
Event.rb file

scope :expired_or_closed_events, -> {where(['close = ?', true] || ['date < ?', Date.current])}

scope :expired_events, -> {where(['date < ?', Date.current])}
scope :closed_events, -> {where(['close = ?', true])}
```

> PROBLEM: This is the below issue i am having. The scope
>   `events.expired_or_closed_events.count` or
>   `events.closed_events.expired_events.count` should display a total
>   count of `5`. Could one kindly advise me how i write a scope thats
>   display all events that are `closed but not expired & that are closed and expired`

-

```
2.3.0 :002 > events.count
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "events"
 => 8 
2.3.0 :003 > 
2.3.0 :004 >   
2.3.0 :005 >   events.closed_events.count
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "events" WHERE (close = 't')
 => 1 
2.3.0 :006 > 
2.3.0 :007 >   
2.3.0 :008 >   events.expired_events.count
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "events" WHERE (date < '2016-11-19')
 => 4 
2.3.0 :009 > 
2.3.0 :010 >   
2.3.0 :011 >   
2.3.0 :012 >   events.expired_or_closed_events.count
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "events" WHERE (close = 't')
 => 1 
2.3.0 :013 > 
2.3.0 :014 >   
2.3.0 :015 >   
2.3.0 :016 >   events.closed_events.expired_events.count
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "events" WHERE (close = 't') AND (date < '2016-11-19')
 => 0 
2.3.0 :017 >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can try mixed Ruby with SQL way:

```
scope :expired_or_closed_events, -> { where('close = ? OR date < ?', true, Date.current) }

scope :expired_events, -> { where('date < ?', Date.current) }
scope :closed_events, -> { where(close: true) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like following:

```
 scope :expired_or_closed_events, -> {where("close = 't' or date < '#{Date.current}'")}
```